# One app have was removed from play store. How many before my account is terminated?

Tags: google-play, admob

Recently, I have received a message from Google Play Developer saying that one app was removed:

> This app has been removed from Google Play for a violation of the
>   Google Play Developer Program Policy regarding Ad Walls and
>   Interstitial Ads. For additional information, please review the
>   interstitial ads help article, then correct your app's ads and
>   resubmit. Additional details have been sent to your account owner's
>   email address.

So I've heard that if I get 3 strikes like this one, my account will be terminated. Is that true?

Also, I am only using Admob ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's policy here states that

> **Removals**
>   **Don’t impact the standing of your Google Play Developer account.**
>   Once your app is removed, the published version of your app won’t be available on Google Play until a compliant updated is submitted.

The message you quoted says that your app was removed, so you don't have much to worry. You just have to be more careful about following the Ads guidelines. They don't want you to keep publishing many apps that don't follow the rules.

---

Also, they don't define exactly how many Suspensions you can have:

> **Suspensions**
>   Count as strikes against the good standing of your Google Play Developer account.
>   Egregious or multiple policy violations **can result in suspension, as can repeated app rejections or removals.**

But 3, as you mentioned, seems a fair number in a short period. Remeber: your apps won't be suspended for nothing, so take care to follow correctly the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It says right there that "Additional details have been sent to your account owner's email address".  So that would be the place to look to get the specifics.

There are a variety of reasons that your app may have been reported.  For instance, you should probably let people know that there are ads at all.  Is your app rated as "kid friendly" but the ads are not?

I'm going to guess that it has something to do with placement.  For instance, if people are clicking your ad accidentally because it's too close to another actionable item, that will get you in trouble.
It could also be because someone is clicking the ad repeatedly, during testing, or to be a joker.  And it's raising a flag.

You really need to do your own research to find out what the problem is.

Once you've done with that, correct the problem and try again.

Comment: and how many strikes like these ones do i need to terminate my account ?

Comment: I do not know that offhand.  But if you're concerned about that, you should pull that app down right away.  You don't want to take a chance on compromising your entire account.